# How to transfer message from php to java base java cluster

Tags: java, php, cluster-computing, load-balancing

php send message to java.But java is cluster.which method is the best.

1. .nginx between php and java.
2. mq between php and java.
3. other choices.
   I need to achieve high-available load-balancer.
   Thanks

Answer (score 0):

i dont know the exact syntax but you need to echo whatever you want in your php 
and get what you echo in java code ;

pseodo code :

url myUrl = open url(http:// ... //my.php);

string temp = myurl.getString();